# Importing project in sts

Tags: java, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I am importing a project into the Spring Tool Suite (STS). My `web.xml` file is giving error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
  <context-param>


error : on line  `***<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>***`
```

> The errors below were detected when validating the file `javaee_5.xsd` via the file `web.xml`. In most cases these errors can be detected by validating `javaee_5.xsd` directly. However it is possible that errors will only occur when `javaee_5.xsd` is validated in the context of `web.xml`.